# Why isn't the Community bot silent when editing posts that have http://* to https://* for stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion, community-user, ssl

For example
https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/144821/revisions

[image: replaced http://unix.stackexchange.com/ with https://unix.stackexchange.com/]
[image: edited Apr 13 at 12:36 Community♦]

Why does this show on the post, wouldn't it be better just to show it in the revision log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regards to edit history, edits by the community bot aren't treated differently than edits by a normal user. Hiding those edits would require writing custom code just for community edits.

But more importantly, the Community bot can make mistakes like any other user. Sometimes community bot edits can unintentionally change the contents of a post. If a mistake was made and we showed the last 'human' user as the last editor, it would give the impression that the human editor was the one that made the mistake.

In short, we show minor edits from regular users in the history. Why treat edits by the Community user any differently?

Comment: It also explains Community's 17k edits in that site alone as well and doesn't cause confusion about who made the edit